# Ошибка в функции accept() Invalid argument

Tags: c++, linux, сервер, сокет, чат

Сделал простой чат через 127.0.1.1. Код клиентской части работает. Код сервера тоже. Но если я начинаю вносить некоторые незначительные изменения в код сервера, то он выдаёт ошибку при вызове :

> accept() - Invalid argument

Причем какие-то изменения нормально переносит, а какие-то нет. Компилятор GNU GCC с поддержкой С++ 11 из `Code::Block`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <sched.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <signal.h>
#include <memory>

const int PORTNUM = 15000;
const int STACK_SIZE = (1024*1024);
std::map<int, std::string> clients;
//int newsock; // Эта строка, например вызывает ошибку,
             // когда хотел сделать переменную newsock глобальной

int login(void *p);
int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::cin;
    std::string buf;
    buf.reserve(100);
    std::pair<int, std::string> temp(0, "o");

    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * ptm;

    sigset_t set1, newset, oldset;
    //sigemptyset(&set1); -  начиная с этой строки тоже начинает выдавать
                          // ошибку, если закоментить то все в порядке
    //sigemptyset(&newset);
    //sigemptyset(&oldset);
    //sigaddset(&set1, SIGUSR1);
    //sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set1, &oldset);
    //sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, 0, &newset);

    socklen_t len;
    int listener;
    int newsock;
    int nbytes;
    sockaddr_in serv_addr, clnt_addr;
    hostent* hp; // структура для ф-ции преобразования имени в адрес
    int* pstart;
    int* pend;
    char hname[80];
    char bufer[100];
    char timebuf[20];

    if ((listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) // создание сокета испльзующего TCP
    {
        perror("Ошибка вызова socket()\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    fcntl(listener, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    gethostname(hname, 80);
    hp = gethostbyname(hname);
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr)); // обнуление и получение адреса процесса hp->h_addrtype
    bcopy(hp->h_addr, &serv_addr.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons((ushort)PORTNUM);
    if (bind(listener, (sockaddr* ) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1) // связывание адреса с сокетом
    {
        perror("Ошибка вызова bind()");
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cerr << "Сервер готов: " << inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr) << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Домен: " << hp->h_name << std::endl;

    if ((listen(listener, 20)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Ошибка вызова listen()");
        exit(1);
    }
    clients.clear();
    fd_set readset;

    while (1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readset);
        FD_SET(listener, &readset);

        // заполнение параметров для select()
        for (std::map<int, std::string>::iterator iter = clients.begin(); iter != clients.end(); iter++)
            FD_SET((*iter).first, &readset);
        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 2;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        if (clients.size() > 0)
        {
            temp = *std::max_element(clients.begin(), clients.end(), clients.value_comp());
        }
        int big = std::max(listener, temp.first);

        if((select(big+1, &readset, 0, 0, &timeout)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Ошибка вызова select()");
            exit(1);
        }

        // обработка потревоженных сокетов
        if(FD_ISSET(listener, &readset))   // Сработал слушающий сокет
        {
            if((newsock = accept(listener, (sockaddr*) &clnt_addr, &len)) < 0)
            {
                perror("Ошибка вызова accept()");
                exit(1);
            }
            // стэк для новой нити
            pstart = new (std::nothrow)int[STACK_SIZE];
            if(pstart == NULL)
            {
                perror("Ошибка new");
                exit(1);
            }
            pend = pstart + STACK_SIZE -1;
            clone(login, pend, CLONE_VM, &newsock);    // порождение thread для логина
        }

        // обработка входящих пакетов для читающих сокетов
        for(std::map<int, std::string>::iterator iter = clients.begin(); iter != clients.end(); iter++)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET((*iter).first, &readset))
            {
               if((nbytes = recv((*iter).first, bufer, sizeof(bufer) + 1, 0)) < 0)
               {
                   std::cerr << "Ошибка вызова recv()" << endl;
                   close((*iter).first);   // связь с удаленным клиентом прервалась, закрываем сокет
                   clients.erase(iter);
                   continue;
               }
               else if(nbytes <= 1) continue;

               // задание времени
               time(&rawtime);
               ptm = gmtime(&rawtime);
               sprintf(timebuf, "%d:%d:%d ", (ptm->tm_hour + 3)%24, ptm->tm_min, ptm->tm_sec);
               if(ptm->tm_sec < 10)
                    {
                       if (ptm->tm_min < 10 && ptm->tm_sec < 10)
                       sprintf(timebuf, "%d:0%d:%0d ", (ptm->tm_hour + 3)%24, ptm->tm_min, ptm->tm_sec);
                       if (ptm->tm_min < 10 && ptm->tm_sec >= 10)
                       sprintf(timebuf, "%d:0%d:%d ", (ptm->tm_hour + 3)%24, ptm->tm_min, ptm->tm_sec);
                    }
               if(ptm->tm_min < 10)
                   {
                       if (ptm->tm_min < 10 && ptm->tm_sec < 10)
                       sprintf(timebuf, "%d:0%d:%0d ", (ptm->tm_hour + 3)%24, ptm->tm_min, ptm->tm_sec);
                       if (ptm->tm_min < 10 && ptm->tm_sec >= 10)
                       sprintf(timebuf, "%d:0%d:%d ", (ptm->tm_hour + 3)%24, ptm->tm_min, ptm->tm_sec);
                   }

               buf = timebuf + (*iter).second + ":: " + bufer;

               // рассылка всем клиентам серевера
               for(std::map<int, std::string>::iterator iter = clients.begin(); iter != clients.end(); iter++)
               {
                   nbytes = send((*iter).first, buf.c_str(), buf.size() + 1, 0);
                   if (nbytes < 0)
                   {
                       perror("Ошибка вызова сервером send()");
                       close((*iter).first);
                       clients.erase(iter);
                       break;
                   }
               }
               buf[0] = '\0';
            }
        };
    }
    close (listener);
    return 0;
}

int login(void *p)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    std::string askname, name;
    std::pair<int, std::string> temp(0, "o");
    int nbytes;
    int *pnewsock = (int*) p;
    char buf[80];

    askname = "Ваш псевдоним для чата: ";
    nbytes = send(*pnewsock, askname.c_str(), askname.size() + 1, 0);
    if(nbytes < 0)
    {
        perror("Ошибка вызова send() при регистрации");
        close(*pnewsock);
    }
    // проверка логина
    do
    {
        if (nbytes < 2)
        {
            askname = "Псевдоним не должен быть нулевой длины: ";
            nbytes = send(*pnewsock, askname.c_str(), askname.size() + 1, 0);
            if(nbytes < 0)
            {
                perror("Ошибка вызова send() при регистрации");
                close(*pnewsock);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        nbytes = recv(*pnewsock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        if(nbytes < 0)
        {
            perror("Ошибка вызова recv() при регистрации");
            close(*pnewsock);
            exit(1);
        }
        std::cerr << nbytes <<std::endl;
    }while (nbytes < 2);

    fcntl(*pnewsock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    name = buf;
    temp.first = *pnewsock;
    temp.second = name;
    clients.insert(temp);
    askname = "Ваш псевдоним - " + name;
    nbytes = send(*pnewsock, askname.c_str(), askname.size() + 1, 0);
    if(nbytes < 0)
    {
        perror("Ошибка вызова send() при регистрации");
        close(*pnewsock);
        exit(1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Надо удалить выделенную new память, но не могу передать соответствующий аргумент в виде структуры, так как если добавить в глобальную область объявление структуры, то вылезет та же ошибка :

> accept(): Invalid argument;

Comment: Уменьшите количество кода, оставив только проблемную часть

Comment: Я как раз и не знаю в какой части проблема. Видимо дело в создании виртуального образа программы.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще нужен clone если он обрабатывает лишь малую часть работы с клиентом и потом добавляет клиента в список, находясь в своем потоке. А что если в это время другой поток то же добавляет/удаляет. Да и пока текущий select не завершится, он не узнает что в списке чтения новый сокет должен появится. все это вместе взятое приведет к сложно вылавливаемым  глюкам

Comment: да, действительно, при одновременной регистрации выдаёт ошибку, но я пока только с этим разбираюсь.
clone() потребовался, так как fork() порождает процесс, который не может изменить глобальную переменную - clients, а clone() может.
В select() таймаут всего 2 секунды, Поэтому в этом проблемы нет.

Comment: @Mike проблему с одновременной регистрацией решил через массив int для сокетов. Теперь каждый поток работает с указателем на уникальный элемент, а не на один и тот же, как было в приведенном мною коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В accept последним параметром должен идти размер предыдущей структуры. А Вы передаете туда данные из неинициализированной области. Что у Вас находится в len? Инициализируйте переменную размером структуры

```
socklen_t len = sizeof (clnt_addr);
```

Comment: Спасибо, проблема и в самом деле была в этом

Comment: @Roman Markov Пожалуйста. И заглядывайте иногда на [opennet.ru](https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=accept&category=2).

Comment: постоянно там бываю, но что-то не сообразил

Comment: @Roman Markov Вообще, неинициализированные переменные - это очень распространенная ошибка новичков, которая может приводить к неприятным последствиям. Программа может замечательно работать на этапе отладки. А потом без причины (и вот так как у Вас, периодически) иногда вываливаться. Просто возьмите себе за правило и заставляйте себя все переменные инициализировать, чтобы в них не было мусора. Даже если Вам кажется, что в этом нет необходимости.